# PyTorch out of GPU memory just after initialization

Tags: python, out-of-memory, gpu, cpu, pytorch

I built my model in PyTorch. **The code works well on CPU**. However, it seems to be running out of GPU memory **just after initializing the network and switching it to cuda**.

The failed code is:

```
model = init_from_scratch(args, train_exs, dev_exs)
model.init_optimizer()

nParams= sum([np.prod(list(p.size())) for p in model.network.parameters()])
print('* total number of parameters:',nParams)

device = torch.device("cuda:"+str(args.gpu) if args.cuda else "cpu")
model.set_device(device) #call last!!

# DATA ITERATORS  (not run to here)
train_dataset = data.ReaderDataset()
train_sampler = torch.utils.data.sampler.RandomSampler()
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader()
...


# TRAIN (not run to here)
for epoch in range(start_epoch, args.num_epochs):
....

def set_device(self,device):
    print("device",device)
    self.use_cuda = False if str(device) == "cpu" else True
    self.network = self.network.to(device)
```

- total number of parameters: 30708906
- Torch version is '0.4.0'
- TITAN Xp with 12G GPU memory and nvidia-smi shows it free

So, what's wrong with my code?

The error output is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "script/train2.0.py", line 683, in <module>
  main(args)
File "script/train2.0.py", line 542, in main
  model.set_device(device)
File "./model.py", line 588, in set_device
  self.network = self.network.to(device)
File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 393, in to
  return self._apply(lambda t: t.to(device))
File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 176, in _apply
  module._apply(fn)
File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 182, in _apply
  param.data = fn(param.data)
File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 393, in <lambda>
  return self._apply(lambda t: t.to(device))
File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py", line 161, in _lazy_init
  torch._C._cuda_init()
```

RuntimeError: cuda runtime error (2) : out of memory at /pytorch/aten/src/THC/THCTensorRandom.cu:25

Comment: Mind pasting the actual error output?

Comment: Is GPU memory actually full? (check for example with GPU-Z)
And yes, error output will help

Comment: Your dataset, probably, was loading into GPU memory too. Can you please check your dataset size and available GPU memory before loading of your model + data?

Comment: nvidia-smi shows that the GPU is almost free. I load the dataset `train_dataset = data.ReaderDataset(),train_sampler = torch.utils.data.sampler.RandomSampler(),train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader()` after the failed code line......

Comment: @zoekeke: It's a bit strange. Can you please try reinstalling of pytorch and cudnn as it recommended here - https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/cuda-runtime-error-out-of-memory/17771